# worklight dojo bb 7 roundrectlist trackpad not used

Tags: dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

i get a simple dojo example with a roundrectlist.

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.RoundRectList" id="results" >
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" >item1</div>
        <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" >item2</div>
</div>
```

executing it on the blackberry device os 7, the trackpad is not used to navigate in the list.
instead i have to move the mouse pointer and press enter key.
What is specific code to add or may be dojo isn't the right framework for bb.
Worklight 5.0.5
thanks.
regards
jack

Comment: seems we need to add a js file from BB ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this page can help:

https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/using_the_navigation_mode_1866978_11.html

Regards,

```
Eric
```